# How to make javascript work on theme options page

Tags: theme-development, jquery, theme-options

Gentlemen!

I'm composing a theme options page for my WP theme. And I bumped into the problem of finding the proper way to introduce inline jQuery interactions to the page.

Ideally for me in the situation will be inline jQ code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on({
        ready: function(){
            alert('Hey!');
        }
    })
</script>
```

But this code fails because I guess the admin options page is rendered before the jQuery is included so js generates expected error. The same code with no jQ identifiers works ok means I get alert window when introduce:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     alert('Hey!');
</script>
```

Question is how to properly introduce inline js containing jQ (or any other framework) syntax and make it work?

Comment: Why do you want to use inline JavaScript and not include a JavaScript file? And if you have a reason to use inline

Comment: Hi I need to use some values stored in WP database. Something like `alert('<? echo get_option("some-stuff"); ?>');`

Comment: Does your code generate JavaScript errors (check using the developer console)? It could be a conflict with another library over `$`. Have you tried `jQuery( document )`?

Comment: `jQuery(...)` did the trick! Thanks!! Can you publish it as an answer so I can mark it as helpful? Cheers!!

Comment: No problem! I've just added it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is, as we found out in the comments on the question, that you're using `$`, which is either undefined or has a conflict (in any case, it's not pointing to `jQuery`).

Using `jQuery( document )` instead of `$( document )` should do the trick!